# How to build Mongodb 3.4 (mongod) for Debian 8 Jessie (stable)?

Tags: mongodb, gcc, deb

I have forked and modified a minor thing from the official mongodb repository on stable branch 3.4.

I am building in a fresh VM installed from scratch with required packages to build the source.

Build instructions impose GCC 5.3 which is not available in the stable distribution of debian 8. If I switch to unstable and compile, (it works yay but) the output executable is >600MB and does not run on a stable debian that has GCC 4.9.

**Question 1**: how is it possible that my build is 10 times bigger in size than the version proposed in the mongodb debian 8 repository ?

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 52M Sep 11 17:50 /usr/bin/mongod

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 664M Oct 28 11:50 /build/mongod
```

**Question 2**: moreover, my built version cannot run on debian 8 stable becauses it uses GCC 5.3 which is not available in stable. So how can I build it such that it runs on the stable debian 8 just like the package repository that mongodb provides ?

If I try to build using GCC 4.9.2, despite some errors that I can eventually fix, it still is a hell to compile. Does that mean they have some magic tricks ?

```
# scons core -j 3 --ssl --link-model=object --opt=on --dbg=off --disable-minimum-compiler-version-enforcement --disable-warnings-as-errors

[...]

src/mongo/db/repl/storage_interface_mock.h:50: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for mongo::repl::CollectionBulkLoaderMock'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
```

I can see that there is a special directory `debian` in the source repository, could that maybe somehow could be used to build the debian package. How should I use it ? Would that make it run on debian 8 stable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1**: The executable output contains debug symbols that can be removed from the binary using the `strip` linux command. This reduces the file size back to ~50MB

**Answer to Question 2**: In order to build for Debian 8 stable, one should not use the GCC compiler but rather use CLANG. The documented minimum verson is 3.4 and version 3.5 is in the stable debian 8 packages.

There are some minor compilation issues though and issues in the Scons compile scripts (python). But after fixing those, it produces an executable able to run on debian 8 stable.

```
scons core -j 3 --ssl --link-model=object --opt=on --dbg=off --disable-minimum-compiler-version-enforcement --disable-warnings-as-errors CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```